# Checking unique value for a variable in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
            Owner        Vehicle_Color
0          James              Red
1          Peter              Green
2          James              Blue
3          Sally              Blue
4          Steven             Red
5          James              Blue
6          James              Red
7          Peter              Blue
```

And I am trying to verify whether one `Owner` has one or multiple vehicle colors assigned to the person. Keeping in mind that my dataframe has more than a million number of different entries for owners (which can be duplicate), what would be the best solution?

Comment: What do you want to do if there are multiple colours assigned?

Comment: @coldspeed Hey coldspeed, ideally each owner should have just 1 color assigned and any with more than 1 color are an error, so just the name of the owner would suffice. I am hoping it doesnt go that far and below answer by student will be just fine..(fingers crossed)

Comment: Well, the answer would've depended on what you wanted to do... error out? Delete the rows? Etc? Also, can the same (name, color) pair occur more than once?

Comment: Ideally just to show the name of the owner in this case. Both name and color can occur more than once. Having said that a simpler method would be to check the number of unique values the nunique code from below would show.

Comment: FYI
    `df.groupby('Owner')['Vehicle_Color'].nunique().unique()` has returned `array([1], dtype=int64)` so its fine! but I would still need to check whether this is the case for the overall data

Comment: `df.groupby('Owner')['Vehicle_Color'].nunique().eq(1).all()` would be better.

Comment: @coldspeed `True`. Beauty, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way may be to use `groupby` and `nunique`:

```
df.groupby('Owner')['Vehicle_Color'].nunique()
```

Results:

```
Owner
James     2
Peter     2
Sally     1
Steven    1
Name: Vehicle_Color, dtype: int64
```